# TableLayout Vs Recycler View?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, tablelayout

I am developing an android app which will allow users to create polls. A user can create a question and provide a set of options.

I wanted to provide a feature in which users can add or remove options dynamically.

I can't decide which layout would be best.

TableLayout - Each row can contain an option. 
Vs
RecyclerView - Each item can be an option.

(Note that each option actually would be an EditText View where the user has to enter the option content.)

I have seen people generally use the RecyclerView for very large data sets but for my use case, a user can add a maximum of 5 or 6 options. Apart from that, I'll be using a recycler view to collect the data. 
For such a use case, is it a good option to use the RecyclerView or something else?

Please provide suggestions

Comment: I would say Recyclerview sounds perfect for your needs. easier than programmatically manipulating layouts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Definitely [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html).
With a `RecyclerView` you can easily add and remove items dynamically.

Use the `TableLayout` if you have a static amount of rows (`TableRow`), that you declare in XML.

Answer (score 1):

Use RecyclerView even if your rows are such little (5 or 6). By doing that, you will facilitate navigation for user with just one screen.